# torch.cuda.is_available() == False

Tags: python, cuda, pytorch, nvidia

Установил убунту 16.04. После pytorch через 'conda'.
Также поставил CUDA 9.0 по гайду: https://gist.github.com/zhanwenchen/e520767a409325d9961072f666815bb8.
Но `import torch; torch.cuda.is_available()` выводит `False`.

Также выводит:

```
torch.cuda.current_device()
AssertionError: 
Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you
have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from ...
```

Вывод команд возможно полезных:

> nvcc --version
>   nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
>   Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
>   Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:03_CDT_2017
>   Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176
>   nvidia-detector 
>   none

до того как попробовал разные комбинации cuda и драйверов nvidia, ошибка указывала на старую версию драйверов.

Answer (score 0):

В первую очередь устанавливается cuda и только после нее pytorch

Попробуйте переустановить pytorch в соответствии с Вашей конфигурацией https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/